# I am getting an error: line 5: conditional binary operator expected ; syntax error near `%' ; line 5: `if [[ $i % 2 = 0 ]]'

Tags: bash

I am getting an error which is:

```
exam.sh: line 5: conditional binary operator expected
exam.sh: line 5: syntax error near `%'
exam.sh: line 5: `if [[ $i % 2 = 0 ]]'
```

Here is my program code:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
i=1;
for user in "$@" 
do
if [[ $i % 2 = 0 ]]
   then
   cd even
   mkdir $user
   .
   else if  [[ $i % 3 = 0 ]]
      then
      cd three
      mkdir $user
      .
      else 
        cd other 
        mkdir $user
   fi 
fi
i=$((i + 1));
done
```

Comment: `%` is not a valid operator for `[[`.  See the section _CONDITIONAL EXPRESSIONS_ in the bash man page.

Answer (score 1):

`[[` doesn't do arithmetics. You need `((` for that.

```sh
if (( i % 2 == 0 ))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use `$((...))` to generate a C-style
"boolean" that you can test explicitly.

```
if [ "$(( x % 2 == 0 ))" = 1 ]; then
    echo "$x is even"
fi
```

This is objectively worse than `if (( x % 2 == 0 ))` in `bash`, but is useful if you need strict POSIX compliance.